# Is it possible to install React.js without node.js/npm on Windows enviroment

Tags: reactjs

Due to being behind a corporate firewall `npm install react` fails due to SSL.

Is there any way to download and install a full setup of react manually without using node.js/npm.

Comment: What is "it"? I assume you will still be wanting to use Node, so you are then talking about manually downloading the NPM module? if so this question is not really about react.

Comment: Edited.........

Comment: You could download each package manually from github, it's going to be very painful though.

Comment: Use builded version https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react from there

Answer (score -1):

Use npm command:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Comment: Could you explain how this will help the OP?

Comment: 'npm config set strict-ssl false' mean is You would not use SSL protocol always